# TreeView Doesn't Fill with nodes

Tags: c#

Could you help me with some problems? I tried to fill treeview nodes with code showed down here.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        LoadFoldersInTreeView(treeView1);
    }
    
    private void LoadFoldersInTreeView(TreeView treeName)
    {            
        treeName.BeginUpdate();
        treeName.Nodes.Add(@"D:\");
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Incoming");
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
        node.Text = "Files";
        GetFolders(dirInfo, node);
        treeName.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(node);
        treeName.Update();
    }

    private void GetFolders(DirectoryInfo dirInfo, TreeNode node)
    {
        DirectoryInfo[] dInfo = dirInfo.GetDirectories();

        if (dInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();

            foreach (DirectoryInfo driSub in dInfo)
            {
                treeNode = node.Nodes.Add(text: driSub.FullName);
                GetFolders(driSub, treeNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I call this procedure from `InitializeComponent();` TreeView have filled, but when I call it from `checkedListBox1_ItemCheck` nothing happens.

But I need to fill this tree only when item checked.

Comment: What does `StartLoadTreeView()` do? Did you  mean `LoadFoldersInTreeView`? BTW you missed `treeName.EndUpdate();` in the last one.

Comment: Yes, there must be _LoadFoldersInTreeView_. Thank you, but _treeName.EndUpdate();_ doesn't helps.

Comment: I tried your code and it works but in some strange way. After checking any checkbox a folder content was added under new "Files" node. I think, you should to clear treeview nodes before rescanning a folder. And what does should be in `checkedListBox1`?

Comment: I just try to work with these controls and don't configure full work process. `checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString()` to understand what item I have checked.
I don't understand why it doesn't work for me.TreeView still hasn't filled.

Comment: I have changed the code and it still doesn't work. Can you try this code?

Comment: BeginUpdate turns off any drawing of the TreeView, so you need EndUpdate to turn drawing back on.  If the code works from the constructor and not from the CheckChanged method, make sure the CheckChanged event is subscribed.

Comment: As @LarsTech, mentioned, it should be `treeName.EndUpdate();` at the last line of `LoadFoldersInTreeView`. With this correction your code worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Miamy and LarsTech, all your advice works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me

[image: fig1]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        FillDriveFolders("E:", treeView1);
    }

    public void FillDriveFolders(string drive, TreeView tree)
    {
        DriveInfo info = new DriveInfo(drive);
        DirectoryInfo root = info.RootDirectory;
        tree.BeginUpdate();
        tree.Nodes.Clear();
        TreeNode node = tree.Nodes.Add(root.Name);
        node.Tag = root;
        RecurseFolders(node, root);
        tree.EndUpdate();
    }

    private void RecurseFolders(TreeNode node, DirectoryInfo root)
    {
        foreach (var dir in root.EnumerateDirectories())
        {
            TreeNode sub = node.Nodes.Add(dir.Name);
            sub.Tag = dir;
            RecurseFolders(sub, dir);
        }
    }
}
```